# openapi 3 kotlin-spring cannot import interface

Tags: spring, kotlin, openapi

I've generated a kotlin-spring server side library, the api classes cannot be imported so I can implement them in my server app. I see the library and its contents in my project but simply cannot import them (IntelliJ), seems to be a very basic problem but I have no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the default packaging, if you run into the same issue have a look at this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-and-normal

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to the `build.gradle.kt`

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir("$rootDir/build/generate-resources/main/src/main/kotlin")
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure the path to the generated files fits in your project. For me it was `$rootDir/build/generate-resources/main/src/main/kotlin`, but could be different for you ->
basically it should be a path from the root up till `com` folder